# d3js tree.nodes() is not a function

Tags: d3.js

While the below piece of code works find in d3v3, it fails in v4.

```
 var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: tree.nodes is not a function

What is the alternative for it in v4?

Comment: Can u suggest what to be done, in JS

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import { hierarchy, tree } from 'd3-hierarchy'

// create a hierarchy from the root
const treeRoot = hierarchy(root)
tree(treeRoot)
// nodes
const nodes = treeRoot.descendants()
// links
const links = treeRoot.links()
```

Comment: Can you make is Javascript rather than TS?

Comment: Answering questions is a genuine attempt by participants.  Its simply unethical to downvote, without citing reason. So, I upvote to nullify that stupid downvote.

Comment: for pure javascript, skip imports and write `d3.hierarchy(root)` instead of `hierarchy(root)` etc.