# D3 v5 radial tree/cluster

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The goal here is to adapt a d3 v3 radial tree chart to v5 using the new `.linkHorizontal()` function that was introduced in more recent versions of d3. Here is the snipped with hard-coded data:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var root = {"name" : "Araneae", "children" : [
                    {"name" : "Agelenidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Hobo Spider"},
       {"name" : "Giant House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Domestic House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Dust Spider"}
      ] },
      {"name" : "Araneidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Grass Spider"},
       {"name" : "Cross Orb Weaver"},
       {"name" : "Banded Garden Spider"},
       {"name" : "Golden Orb Weaver Spider"},
       {"name" : "Long-Jawed Orb Weaver Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Ctenidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Brazilian Wandering Spider"},
       {"name" : "Fishing Spider"}
                    ] },
                    {"name" : "Desidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Black House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Hollow Twig Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Filistatidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Southern House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Arizona Black Hole Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Lycosidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Carolina Wolf Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown Wolf Spider"},
       {"name" : "Texas Wolf Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Pholcidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Cellar Spider"},
       {"name" : "Yellow Sac Spider"},
       {"name" : "Ground Spider"},
       {"name" : "Banded Garden Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Salticidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Bold Jumping Spider"},
       {"name" : "Zebra Jumping Spider"},
       {"name" : "Gray Wall Jumping Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Sicariidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Brown Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown Recluse Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Theraphosidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "King Baboon Spider"},
       {"name" : "Bird Eating Spider"},
       {"name" : "Pinktoe Tarantula Spider"},
       {"name" : "Indian Ornamental Tree Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Theridiidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Black Widow Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown Widow Spider"},
       {"name" : "Red Widow Spider"}
      ] }
                ]};


var diameter = 760;

var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 190])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

    var diagonal = function link(d) {
      return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
          + "C" + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x
          + " " + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.target.x
          + " " + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x;
    };


    const treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root)
    d3.tree(treeRoot)

    const nodes = treeRoot.descendants()

    const links = treeRoot.links()

 var link = graphGroup.selectAll(".link")
 .data(links)
   .enter().append("path")
 .attr("class", "link")
 .attr("d", diagonal);

 var node = graphGroup.selectAll(".node")
 .data(nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "node")
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

 node.append("circle")
 .attr("r", 5);

 node.append("text")
 .attr("dy", ".31em")
 .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)"; })
 .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter - 150 + "px");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

This gives me the error:

> Error: path attribute d: expected number, "Mundefined,undefin..."

Original v3 version here:

http://bl.ocks.org/nlinc1905/66ea5dd294ed28385b7f

As you can see there is no issue with the v3 version, however, I can't get it working for v5 -- even after making changes as per [d3js tree.nodes() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087568/d3js-tree-nodes-is-not-a-function). Namely:

```
var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 190])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });
var diagonal = function link(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
      + "C" + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x
      + " " + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.target.x
      + " " + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x;
};


const treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root)
d3.tree(treeRoot)

const nodes = treeRoot.descendants()

const links = treeRoot.links()
```

Also tried (per comments):

```
var treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root);

treeRoot = d3.tree(treeRoot);
```

### Question

What is the issue with my v5 radial tree syntax and how might I resolve it?

Comment: have you tried var treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root), treeRoot =  d3.tree(treeRoot)

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi Thanks for the tip, but I still got an error: "treeRoot.descendants" is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Mm, this was not answered because it had several issues (hierarchy, radial projection, styling lines). Solved below, I guess this is what it was meant to be (probably needs adjusting labels):

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+(width/2-margins.left)+","+(height/2-margins.top)+")");

var root = {"name" : "Araneae", "children" : [
                    {"name" : "Agelenidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Hobo Spider"},
       {"name" : "Giant House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Domestic House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Dust Spider"}
      ] },
      {"name" : "Araneidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Grass Spider"},
       {"name" : "Cross Orb Weaver"},
       {"name" : "Banded Garden Spider"},
       {"name" : "Golden Orb Weaver Spider"},
       {"name" : "Long-Jawed Orb Weaver Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Ctenidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Brazilian Wandering Spider"},
       {"name" : "Fishing Spider"}
                    ] },
                    {"name" : "Desidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Black House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Hollow Twig Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Filistatidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Southern House Spider"},
       {"name" : "Arizona Black Hole Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Lycosidae", "children" : [
       {"name" : "Carolina Wolf Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown Wolf Spider"},
       {"name" : "Texas Wolf Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Pholcidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Cellar Spider"},
       {"name" : "Yellow Sac Spider"},
       {"name" : "Ground Spider"},
       {"name" : "Banded Garden Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Salticidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Bold Jumping Spider"},
       {"name" : "Zebra Jumping Spider"},
       {"name" : "Gray Wall Jumping Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Sicariidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Brown Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown Recluse Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Theraphosidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "King Baboon Spider"},
       {"name" : "Bird Eating Spider"},
       {"name" : "Pinktoe Tarantula Spider"},
       {"name" : "Indian Ornamental Tree Spider"}
      ] },
                    {"name" : "Theridiidae", "children": [
       {"name" : "Black Widow Spider"},
       {"name" : "Brown Widow Spider"},
       {"name" : "Red Widow Spider"}
      ] }
                ]};

function radialPoint(x, y) { // returns radial projections of a point coordinates
 return [parseFloat((y = +y) * Math.cos(x -= Math.PI / 2)).toFixed(4), parseFloat(y * Math.sin(x)).toFixed(4)];
}

var diameter = 760;

var hierTree = d3.tree()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 190])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

    var diagonal = function link(d) {
      return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
          + "C" + (d.x + d.parent.x) / 2 + "," + d.y
          + " " + (d.x + d.parent.x) / 2 + "," + d.parent.y
          + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
    };


    var treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root, function(d) { // creates a hierarchy from data read
     return d.children;
    });
    var treeData = hierTree(treeRoot);
//    var treeData = d3.tree(treeRoot)

    var nodes = treeData.descendants();

    var links = nodes.slice(1);

 var link = graphGroup.selectAll(".link")
 .data(links)
   .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", "link")
       .attr("x1", function(d) { return radialPoint(d.x,d.y)[0]; })
       .attr("y1", function(d) { return radialPoint(d.x,d.y)[1]; })
       .attr("x2", function(d) { return radialPoint(d.parent.x,d.parent.y)[0]; })
       .attr("y2", function(d) { return radialPoint(d.parent.x,d.parent.y)[1]; })

 var node = graphGroup.selectAll(".node")
 .data(nodes)
 .enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "node")
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + radialPoint(d.x, d.y) + ")" });

 node.append("circle")
 .attr("r", 5);

 node.append("text")
 .attr("dy", ".31em")
 .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (d.x > 0 && d.x < 180) ? "start" : "end"; })
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "translate(-8)"; })
 .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter - 150 + "px");
```

```css
 .link {
     fill: none;
     stroke: #365CB7;
     stroke-width: 0.8px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I have left the diagonal function to reuse after getting know of script working.